# Where would Zorquan (Forgotten Realms' dragon god of dragonness), be today?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities, dragons

<sub>Related: [**What is the difference between a god and a primordial?** *(see section regarding Dragon gods)*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/92438)

Related: [**Where do dragon souls go after their deaths?**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178761)

Related: [**Are there any other published attestations of Zorquan, besides Draconomicon** *(1990)* **& Cult Of The Dragon** *(1998)***?**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197506)

Related: [**Would Zorquan be a Unity domain patron?**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169939)</sub>

### Among the many planes of D&D 5e,
in *what part* of *what realm*,
might *what aspects* of Zorquan remain?

Way back in D&D 2e,
***Cult of the Dragon* listed Zorquan as a neutral draconic deity**, largely unconcerned with individuals.
The *Draconomicon* stated that Zorquan decried the zealotous bloodshed of the Draconic Holy Wars.

I gather that Zorquan's followers were urged only that dragons should each be true to their own nature. Zorquan seemingly had no diametrically opposed enemies, but Sammaster & anyone who would enslave dragons or destroy all dragons, might have been the most likely to ire the ancient dragon.  (?)

**It appears Zorquan's primary demesnes were reputed to be on the Material Plane, and a neutral plane in the Outlands.**

I've read in some sources, of theories which claim draconic deities were not "true" Gods: Instead, it is believed some "mortal" dragons gained contact with Aspects of themselves from other planes; merging, in something akin to apotheosis. *However* as of 5th edition, Bahamut, Tiamat, & Io, seem to be confirmed as actual Gods, presumably with all the conditionals that entails. (?)

Sounds like Ao assigns domains on Toril, though I've no idea the criteria...

Dating from the years -30,000 to -24,000 DR, Zorquan was counted as a Greatest Wyrm, a High One, & either an Intermediate or a Greater Deity "of dragonness", depending whom you asked.

**In 5e, there's *nothing* published about Zorquan, so far.**

One might presume Zorquan died, either toward the end of the Draconic Holy Wars, or thereafter. However, I find no direct indication of this.

In 5e, the mind of a god apparently leaves a corpse in the Astral plane (with potential regional effects).
Speaking purely in terms of RAW or RAI, would Zorquan be likely to have a corpse in the Astral?
(potentially with Zorquan's memories\thoughts taking tangible forms, there)

Alternatively, might Zorquan still live, somehow?

In short:
**If Zorquan lives, *where?***
**If not, what *(if anything)* is left?**

Comment: There’s at least one answer here that argues draconic gods are not “gods” per se in 5e, but personally I think the passage in question (which says something like “the closest thing dragons have to gods”) is describing the relationship between dragons and their deities (noting the limits on how much dragons truly “worship” anything) than it is a comment on what those deities actually are. This also tracks with my impression of previous editions’ comments on the subject; I think there’s room to argue otherwise but the most likely interpretation is that dragon deities are and always were gods.

Comment: @KRyan Indeed, the section calling draconic deities' godhood into question, was phrased as in-universe *speculation*, not stated as a factual rule. Additionally, that passage seems to give draconic "deities" *more* leeway, in that their contact with other aspects could shore up the deity's existence against a lack of worshippers on any one specific plane? (If most dragons now eschew fervent kow-towing to potentially power-hungry gods, I'd say that reflects well on Zorquan's legacy as a draconic god who urged dragons not to risk extinction over the rivalries of gods!?) If a god, where's home?

Comment: If Zorquan *was* a god, would they now be a *dead god* (with a "corpse" in the astral)? If *not* a god, is the ancient Greatest Wyrm dragon Zorquan's soul, serving a God on another Plane, somewhere? Whether they were a "true" god or not, remaining living or not, I'm struggling to discern where Zorquan would end up having gone to, in the 5e multiverse...?

Comment: I did also answer the question, below; is there something more you’re interested in from an answer?

Comment: He certainly lives on in your Username...

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin No no, my username is *Zarquon*, not **Zorquan**. Huge difference: The "great" Prophet Zarquon prophesied that he would return, then showed up at The Restaurant At The End Of The Universe & said "sorry I'm a bit late" just before the universe ended. Douglas Adams never read nor contributed to AD&D, so far as I'm aware (& I used to read his blogs & listen to his speaking appearances). -- If **Zorquan** actually needed worshippers, one dragon might suffice, but it would make sense to me if Zorquan were a dead god in the astral by now, given no observed followers in two ages.

Comment: *(Incidentally, variants of 'czar khan' appear to be among the oldest known epithets for an 'accepted ruler' or 'king'. I wouldn't be surprised if both fictional names were inspired by the same title\name.)* ... I am not at all certain that (virtually primordial?) ancient Greatest Wyrm "deities" need worshippers on the Material, to continue existing in other aspects on planes? I would think one worshipper *anywhere* might suffice, & Zorq had both Material & Outlands cited; so even if Toril has forgotten Zorquan, a dragon or {n} in the Outlands, might maintain up Zorq's deific status t\here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The most likely place to find Zorquan is exactly where Zorquan always was

The Outlands (and the Material, natch) still exist in 5e;¹ absent any further information on the subject, my assumption would be that Zorquan is still there, same as ever.

On the other hand, the Astral does indeed have a “graveyard” of floating god corpses in it,² and this is an area that is little-explored.³ That means it’s pretty much always possible to add new corpses to it without conflicting with any canon, because canonically no one has a complete survey of what’s there.⁴ Zorquan could be in there without us knowing. Of course, his *absence* in the Outlands (or Material, if you go with that) would be noticed—though that absence was plausibly not reported as far as us, the readers.

But Zorquan was old, even by divine standards, and fairly powerful. Zorquan’s death would not happen easily, or quickly. I wouldn’t take absence of evidence here to be evidence of absence.

1. <sub>*Player’s Handbook* (2014) pg. 302—note that the diagram on pg. 303 doesn’t seem to show it, but it is there.</sub>
2. <sub>Tended to by the Guardian of Dead Gods, formerly known as Anubis. *Deities & Demigods* (1980) pg. 45. Note that later editions of D&D have just put Anubis in the “Pharaonic” pantheon, but this pantheon isn’t really used in official campaign settings. Even in the Forgotten Realms—where the Mulhorandi pantheon was the Pharaonic pantheon allowed into Toril by special dispensation from Ao—makes a point of Anubis not coming with,¹ to leave him available to become the Guardian of Dead Gods.</sub>

   1. <sub>“[Hate of the Cobra](https://web.archive.org/web/20160816193559/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20050209a)” (2005)</sub>
3. <sub>Largely due to the aforementioned Guardian, who is *very* high on the “not to be messed with” scale in the D&D multiverse, much more so even than he was as Anubis.</sub>
4. <sub>Except, maybe, the Guardian, but if he has one, he isn’t sharing it. The githyanki famously built a city, Tu’narath, on one of these god-corpses,¹ as have others,² but even they don’t know the full extent of the graveyard.</sub>

   1. <sub>*Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* (2018) pg. 91-92, most recent among many sources.</sub>
   2. <sub>*Spelljammer* (2022). Note that this book contradicts basically everything about its subject matter as found in prior editions, and should be viewed—apparently in its entirety—with extreme skepticism. No one needs a spelljammer to explore the Astral.</sub>

Comment: Re: foot note 2, the new spelljammer book (released yesterday) might be retconning what you're referencing: "The Astral Sea is also where one can find the petrified remains of gods who were slain by more powerful entities or who lost all their mortal worshipers and perished as a result. A dead god looks like a gigantic, nondescript stone statue that bears little resemblance to the divine entity it once was. Githyanki, mind flayers, psurlons, and other natives of the Astral Plane sometimes turn these drifting hulks into outposts and cities, many of which are hollowed out beneath the surface."

Comment: @KRyan Great analysis in this response! Excellent point that absence of evidence may not be evidence of absence. ... So, if Zorquan did still remain in the Material plane or the Outlands, what part of that plane seems a likely place to find Zorquan; or even find a temple to Zorquan? (Unlike some dragons, no firm locations for Zorq were cited in 2e.) "The north" in Faerun was as far as my guesswork got me. (Perhaps near Mirabar?) I don't know enough lore to know likely shared spaces or other draconic locales. I have *no* concept where such a dragon might be, in the Outlands!? Any specific idea?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I was *really* hoping the new book on Forgotten Realms dragons, or the new Spelljammer books (which heavily feature the Astral), would include some scrap of language which might relate to old Zorq'; but alas, I haven't yet unearthed anything elucidating the few tidbits I gleaned from 2e... Still hoping either I missed something or WotC might still have something to say about it!

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I am not in the habit of treating Wizards of the Coast’s abbreviated treatment of the lore as canonically excising it. If anything, that may add to footnote 4, but seeing as the Guardian always allowed Tu’narath, it doesn’t seem that unlikely he’d allow others, so the presence of others does not imply the absence of the Guardian. (Also, **what on earth?!** is a Spelljammer book doing in the Astral? Spelljammers don’t interact with the Astral at all, their entire purpose is to travel the Material!)

Comment: @KRyan Bad news, the first two volumes are called ***Astral** Adventurer's Guide* and *Boo's **Astral** Menagerie*.

Comment: @KRyan I'd watch what you say, the monster book has this disclaimer: "DISCLAIMER: *SQUEAK SQUEAK* (TRANSLATION: YOU’RE ON BOO’S TURF NOW, WORLD-HUGGER! UNLESS YOU WANT A HAMSTER-KNUCKLE SANDWICH, YOU’D BETTER WATCH WHERE YOU’RE SPELLJAMMING. AND BEFORE YOU BLOW UP A NAUTILOID, MAKE SURE THERE ARE NO SPACE HAMSTERS ABOARD IT. OTHERWISE, PREPARE TO FACE THE WRATH OF BOO!)"

Comment: @ProphetZarquon I don’t think we can really answer more precisely than the 2e sources do on those questions. Perhaps a better lore expert than I could offer some educated thoughts on the subject, but it would be very difficult to back up. So far as I know, dragons aren’t really geographically concentrated in Toril, so anywhere could work. On the Outlands, the more central you are, the more neutral you are, and Zorquan would want to be neutral, but the center is taken by the Spire which Zorquan would have to avoid. No idea which side of the Spire Zorquan would favor though.

Comment: @KRyan It's largely my lack of knowledge for post-2e rules & lore on deities (& draconic deities in particular), which drew me to beg here for details on what the possible outcomes are. I wasn't even sure draconic deities *could* end up as corpses in the astral?! Regarding the Spire... Everything I've learned about The Lady Of Pain sounds very... Zorquan-ish!? Right down to the "don't worship me" bit. I don't know how domains change hands in 5e; would it make sense for Zorquan's remaining aspects in other realms, to appear via The Lady in the Outlands, or a similar deity in the Material?

Comment: I am less concerned with spelljammers plying the Astral, than by the idea that Zorquan's memories & emotions might create an asteroid-like formation or minor realm of some kind???  Regarding Spelljamming the Astral, my understanding of the old cosmology was that once outside a given crystal sphere, you were in the phlogiston; into which the deities we know, cannot exert their power... As such, travel to wildly distant planes seems in some respects more practical via the Astral, than through more material phlogiston? I always thought Spelljammers went *everywhere*, not just for phlogiston...

Comment: I am marking this answer as accepted, but if there are any strong clues from later editions, as to where Zorquan might reside (or repose!) today, I would be interested to see them added to the answer: For instance, Zorquan's alignment implying a possible residence **near the Spire** in the Outlands, seems well-evidenced enough to be worth mentioning in the answer? Likewise, if any text implied that draconic deities or particularly ancient primordial dragons *did not go to the Astral* when out of worshippers; or if a deity (Ao?) had domain over dead dragon gods, that warrants mention too?

Comment: @ProphetZarquon The Lady of Pain is not a deity, and no deity has anything to do with her. The last deity to claim something like that got very dead, very quickly, and she has since kicked all deities out of Sigil. Zorquan, so far as I can tell, opposes worship because worshipping is not a “dragon-ish” thing to do—he instead derives the faith he needs from dragons embracing “dragonness,” including not worshipping. The Lady, by contrast, doesn’t need anyone’s faith; she just is. She outlaws worship of herself because that faith could turn her into a god—weakening her.

Comment: @ProphetZarquon The Spelljammer stuff is tangential; no, they weren’t limited to the phlogiston, but there also isn’t any particular need for one outside the Phlogiston. The only reason anyone bothers with them is because the Phlogiston blocks direct teleportation. There are so many easier ways to get around the Astral; why bother with a spelljammer? It’s just an incredibly dumb ret-con that completely invalidates the entire premise of the product line. But it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @ProphetZarquon As regards your question, there just isn't more information. Zorquan is just extremely obscure, and has not gotten much attention at all. He probably isn’t dead; more likely, Wizards of the Coast just hasn’t mentioned him—and won’t ever mention him—because there isn’t a lot of interest in him. He doesn’t really fill an important role in the cosmos or story. Anything where he might be appropriate, can just be picked up be Bahamut and/or Tiamat, saving them from having to introduce and detail a new character. That kind of saving has been their M.O. since at least 4e.

Comment: Inability to find a neutral draconic deity which would fit as a laid back sort (as opposed to obsessed with perfect balance), was actually why I went looking for more info on Zorquan in the first place: Feels like 5e lacks diversity in draconic deities; which... Zorquan would approve of. Hadn't heard about The Lady Of Pain being weakened if godhood took effect; interesting angle. Does that make her a primordial or an outsider of some kind? I don't know the lore; couldn't find much! I'm still unconvinced of dissimilarity, but this feels as answered as can be for now. Thanks!